The message is logged even though topic is deleted
My tester has found that if a topic is deleted then the logging is still ongoing even if the message is not sent to target. The idea is not to log the Outgoing Enum if we are not sure that the message was successfully sent. Here is the piece of problematic code:
`outputStream.filter((k, v) -> v != null && v.getInput() != null && v.getContent() != null)
                .mapValues(v -> v.getContent())
                .peek((k, v) -> log(enum.getEnumOutgoing(), targetTopic, k))
                .to(targetTopic);`

I have tried already creating a new targetTopic stream. It didn't work, also I tried catching the Timeout Exception which was also not a solution.

Using peek just inspects the ongoing stream. It wouldn't know the status of the cluster. You could try to consume from the output topic to verify if records were sent to it

This one I tried but it doesn't have time to process it that quickly since thousand of messages are coming. There seems to be some delay.
